# How to target a post by a sepecific author?

Tags: author

This is something simple, When a user is visiting a post, I want the code to check the author of the post and then deliver a HTML. Here is what works for category.

```
<?php if( in_category( 412 ) ){?> Some HTML <?php }else ?>
```

Is there anything similar for the Author?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>` And if you would want to use conditional logic you could use `<?php if(get_the_author() === 'Author Name') { ?> Do some HTML <?php } ?>`